# number of functions from one set to the other

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f:\{0,1,2\}→\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ be a function such that for every $i, \, j\in {\{0,1,2\}}$ where 
$i<j$, we have $f(i)<f(j)$. How many such functions can we have?

Taking different cases for functions, I obtained 35 as the total number of functions.

Is considering different cases the only way to answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct, there are $35$ functions that satisfy your condition.

The easiest way to calculate that number is to realize that each function gives you a unique set of three elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, and that each unique set of three elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ defines exactly one function, thus

$$|\{f| \forall i,j\in\{0,1,2\}: i<j\implies f(i)<f(j)\}| = |\{S\subset \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}||S|=3\}|=\\ = {7\choose3}=35$$